# How to implement micronaut dependency in grails gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle, grails, micronaut, micronaut-security

I'm trying to add micronaut dependency in grails build.gradle. And I found no proper solution. And getting the following error.

**build.gradle** file

```
dependencies {
     *these are the dependencies I would like to add*
//    implementation("io.micronaut.reactor:micronaut-reactor")
//    implementation("io.micronaut.reactor:micronaut-reactor-http-client")
//    implementation("io.micronaut.security:micronaut-security-jwt")
//    implementation("io.micronaut.views:micronaut-views-velocity")
//    compileOnly("io.micronaut.security:micronaut-security-annotations")
}
```

I tried adding mavenCentral() and mavenLocal() in the repositories. And it didn't work. Does anyone know how can I implement micronaut dependencies?

**Error**

```
grails:test: Could not find io.micronaut.reactor:micronaut-reactor:.
Required by:
    project :
```

Comment: Which maven repos are you resolving dependencies from?  Are you pulling in a bom which specifies a version number for that dependency?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Gradle what version of the dependencies to pull down.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:3.5.2') // <1>
    implementation("io.micronaut.reactor:micronaut-reactor")
    implementation("io.micronaut.reactor:micronaut-reactor-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut.security:micronaut-security-jwt")
    implementation("io.micronaut.views:micronaut-views-velocity")
    compileOnly("io.micronaut.security:micronaut-security-annotations")
}
```

1. The Bill of materials (BOM), which contains all the dependency version numbers for the Micronaut Framework 3.5.2 release.